# Core Data Saving Incorrectly

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a secondary managed object context that handles incoming sync data before that data gets merged back into the main moc. Unfortunately, I'm running into problems with what appears to be a merge policy issue. The issue is happening not when merging the notification back into the main moc, but prior to that... when the secondary context is saving itself.

The merge policy of the secondary context is NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy. If I remove this policy and let it default back to the typical error, this problem no longer happens. However, I'm trying to understand why this is a problem to begin with, especially because I don't want to use the default merge policy for this context.

I have a User object with an active attribute. When a sync object comes in from the server reactivating the user, the flow goes something like this:

Before applying the change to the object, here is its initial state:

```
(SyncObject *) $29 = 0x0051b6f0 <User: 0x51b6f0> (entity: User; id: 0x526030 <x-coredata://70907366-8102-4131-9230-6F60D0508047/User/p617> ; data: {
active = 0;
...
```

After applying the change to the object, as one would expect:

```
(SyncObject *) $30 = 0x0051b6f0 <User: 0x51b6f0> (entity: User; id: 0x526030 <x-coredata://70907366-8102-4131-9230-6F60D0508047/User/p617> ; data: {
active = 1;
...
```

A little bit later, immediately before the save, I verified the object was still active (it's an int because I po'd the memory address directly in this case):

```
(int) $45 = 5355248 <User: 0x51b6f0> (entity: User; id: 0x526030 <x-coredata://70907366-8102-4131-9230-6F60D0508047/User/p617> ; data: {
active = 1;
...
```

Next we have the save:

```
[syncContext save:&error];
```

And then in the merge notification block I see this when I print the notification:

```
updated = "{(\n    <User: 0x51b6f0> (entity: User;
id: 0x526030 <x-coredata://70907366-8102-4131-9230-6F60D0508047/User/p617> ;
data: {\n    active = 0;\n
...
```

Even worse, the object at that point appears as such:

```
(int) $47 = 5355248 <User: 0x51b6f0> (entity: User; id: 0x526030 <x-coredata://70907366-8102-4131-9230-6F60D0508047/User/p617> ; data: {
active = 0;
...
```

Why does the object in memory appear to be being overwritten by the data in the SQL store? As I understand it, NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy means that differing values in memory will be saved on top of those values in the store, but clearly that's not what's going on. I'm really at a loss, and this problem worries me because it seems to indicate that changes coming in off the server could be being thrown away. If anyone knows more about what's going on here, I'd love to understand what's actually happening.

I should mention that when I do remove the merge policy, this save throws a merge error, as I expected, however I don't understand why it considers my new changes as "old"

```
 (NSError *) $8 = 0x00566720 Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=133020 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 133020.)" UserInfo=0x591c90 {
conflictList=(
"NSMergeConflict (0x5df220) for NSManagedObject (0xd63a370) with objectID '0xd635310 <x-coredata://70907366-8102-4131-9230-6F60D0508047/User/p617>'
with oldVersion = 9 and newVersion = 10
and old object snapshot = {\n    active = 1;\n ...\n} 
and new cached row = {\n    active = 0;\n ... \n}"
)}
```

**Workaround:**

So in my case it was because there were changes being made to this particular object on the main managed object context. Because we have a Core Data Watcher class running (listening to the context save notification), I need to save all changes to that MOC before merging in new ones so that user changes are correctly documented. I *was* doing this save in the NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification block right before the mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification call, which was too late to stop conflicts. By moving it into a NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification, the mainMOC saves its changes to the persistent store, the watcher registers those changes, then the secondary store is free to try and merge its changes into the mainMOC without worry of conflicting with changes the latter might have had queued up.

As a caveat to this, I had to make sure that before I fetched the objects to update on the incoming sync context that I had saved any pending changes to those objects on the main context. It ultimately turns out I was taking a snapshot of the object before it had been saved, so that the changes I was making on one context were out of sync with the changes prepared on another context. While I'm still fuzzy on why the merging was happening the way it was, by making sure I had the most up to date version of the object before attempting to alter it and merge it back in, the merge errors went away and the merge process continued as desired.

Comment: You can add your workaround as an answer and - if nobody has a better answer - accept your own answer.